# Problemas al mostrar parametros en vista parcial

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estoy consumiendo un servicio para consulta de saldos de cliente, el me devuelve como respuesta una entidad con estas propiedades:

```
public string errorCodigoField { get; set; }
public string errorMensajeField { get; set; }
public decimal saldoRecargasField { get; set; }
public decimal saldoServiciosField { get; set; }
```

Con un input button mando a llamar a la acción correspondiente, utilizando jquery:

```
function Actualizar() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Recargas/ConsultaSaldo',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#saldosservicios').html(data);
            }
        });
```

Luego de la llamada, tengo la siguiente condición en el action del controlador, donde se hace el return de la vista parcial:

```
if (saldoInfo.result.errorCodigoField == "00")
{
    ViewBag.SaldoRecargas = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoRecargasField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    ViewBag.SaldoServicios = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoServiciosField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return PartialView("ConsultaSaldo", new { _recargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas, _servicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios });

 }
 else
 {
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Recargas", new { Mensaje = "Ha ocurrido un error en la consulta" });
 }
```

Esta sería la vista parcial:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ConsultaSaldo", "Recargas", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "formSaldos" }))
{
<div class="saldos">
    <div class="saldosservicios">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Servicios</h4>
        @if (ViewBag.SaldoServicios != null)
        {
            <output class="totalsaldo" >@ViewBag.SaldoServicios</output>                
        }
    </div>

    <div class="saldosrecargas">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Recargas</h4>
        @if (ViewBag.SaldoRecargas != null)
        {
           <output class="totalsaldo">@ViewBag.SaldoRecargas</output>
        }           
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="btnConsultar" type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="Actualizar()"/>
    </div>
 </div>
}
```

Y la llamada a la vista parcial desde la vista principal la hago de esta manera:

```
<div id="saldos-section">
    @Html.Partial("ConsultaSaldo", new { SaldoRecargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas, SaldoServicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios })
</div>
```

He notado en la depuración que el ViewBag si contiene los valores esperados:

[image: Valores ViewBag en depuración]

Pero por alguna razón los resultados no se muestran en pantalla. Si pudieran regalarme alguna clase de orientación, estaré muy agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Jesus, bienvenido a [es.so]. Muy buena pregunta para ser la primera! Has hecho algun tipo de log para ver qué puede estar sucediendo para que no se muestre el resultado? tienes errores por consola? Un saludo

Comment: Hola buen día. De momento no tengo errores en la consola relacionados a esto

Comment: Hola, lo unico que logro ver es el uso del tag output el cual no es soportado 100% por todos los navegadores, podrias intentar usando solamente : @ViewBag.SaldoRecargas sin los tags de output?.

Comment: De igual forma he utilizado etiquetas como <label>, <p> o utilizando tu sugerencia pero de igual forma, no se ve el resultado en pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos los que realizaron sus aportes. He encontrado la solución por otros medios por lo que me permito compartirles lo siguiente:

Primero he cambiado el tipo de resultado de la acción de consulta pasando de    `Task<ActionResul>` a `Task<JsonResult>`.

El condicional del `Action` del `Controller` se ve así:

```
if (saldoInfo.result.errorCodigoField == "00")
{
     var SaldoRecargas = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoRecargasField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

     var SaldoServicios = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoServiciosField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

     return Json(new string[] { saldoInfo.result.errorCodigoField, saldoInfo.result.errorMensajeField, SaldoRecargas.ToString(), SaldoServicios.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else
{
     return Json(new string[]{ saldoInfo.result.errorCodigoField, saldoInfo.result.errorMensajeField, "",""}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Se reestructuró la vista parcial, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConsultaSaldo", "Recargas", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "formSaldos" }))
{
<div class="saldos">
    <div class="saldosservicios">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Servicios</h4>
            <output class="totalsaldo" id="outsaldoservicio" ></output>                
    </div>

    <div class="saldosrecargas">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Recargas</h4>
           <output class="totalsaldo" id="outsaldorecargas"></output> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="btnConsultar" type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="Actualizar()"/>
    </div>
    </div>
}
```

El script de la actualización de saldos luce de esta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Actualizar() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Recargas/ConsultaSaldo',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#outsaldoservicio").html(data[3])
                $("#outsaldorecargas").html(data[2])
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Finalmente la llamada de la vista parcial, en la vista principal quedó así:

```
<div id="saldos-section">
            @Html.Partial("ConsultaSaldo", new { SaldoRecargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas, SaldoServicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios })                
</div>
```

Resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que bien que encontraste la solución, por favor marca tu respuesta como correcta para que tu pregunta se marque como "Resuelta".

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea por el elemento output. Outpot en HTML se utiliza para visualizar resultados de operaciones. En este caso estar cargando un dato desde el controlador, Intenta imprimiendo sobre un elemento label y agrega **@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Mydata)**.

```
<label class="totalsaldo">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SaldoRecargas)</label>
```

Comment: También he utilizado <label> para mostrar el resultado. Pero sin exito. Saludos

Comment: Y agregando un break point sobre la linea de la vista parcial, aun te muestra el valor?

Comment: Si. Al agregar el breakpoint justo en la condición el ViewBag.SaldoServicios muestra un valor

Comment: Sabes que? te falta contener el viewbag con @Html.Raw()

Comment: Pero exactamente donde lo utilizo? Gracias por la idea :) Refresh: Acabo de notar la edición del primer comentario. Saludos :D

Comment: Que contenga al ViewBag, edité la respuesta

Comment: Comentar @Aaron que no funciona, he colocado el @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SaldoRecargas) dentro de un label, pero resulta que el label si se "imprime" en el html, mas no el valor del ViewBag

Comment: Ya se volvió medio estraño, que version de MVC usas?

Comment: Actualmente trabajo con MVC 5 y Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: Debería de funcionar ya que estas retornando una vista parcial. Intenta cargar de distinta manera, en vez de ViewBag intentalo con @TempData

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que intentes eliminando el ViewBag :

Modelo

```
public class Saldos
{
    public int SaldoRecargas  { get; set; }
    public int SaldoServicios { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador

```
if (saldoInfo.result.errorCodigoField == "00")
{
    var datos = new Saldos();
    datos.SaldoRecargas = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoRecargasField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    datos.SaldoServicios = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(saldoInfo.result.saldoServiciosField), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return PartialView("ConsultaSaldo", datos);

}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Recargas", new { Mensaje = "Ha ocurrido un error en la consulta" });
}
```

Vista Parcial

```
@model MiNamespace.Saldos

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConsultaSaldo", "Recargas", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div class="saldos">
    <div class="saldosservicios">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Servicios</h4>
        @if (@Model.SaldoServicios != null)
        {
            @Model.SaldoServicios
        }
    </div>

    <div class="saldosrecargas">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Recargas</h4>
        @if (@Model.SaldoRecargas != null)
        {
            @Model.SaldoRecargas
        }           
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="btnConsultar" type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="Actualizar()"/>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Llamada a la vista parcial :

```
<div id="saldos-section">
    @Html.Partial("ConsultaSaldo")
</div>
```

Tambien me gustaría ver completo el codigo de la acción, incluyendo la firma del método.

Comment: Buen día Mauricio. Te comento que he realizado los cambios como has sugerido. Los valores de las propiedades del modelo perfectamente llegan a la vista, sin embargo el detalle es que no se ven reflejadas en la pantalla. Si inserto los valores dentro de una etiqueta html, no se imprime ni el Model.SaldoServicios ni la etiqueta. Saludos

Comment: Has intentado quitando todo lo demas y solo dejando los tags Model.SaldoServicios y Model.SaldoRecargas sin el form, sin los divs, sin los "if"

Answer (score 0):

Al renderizar la vista parcial, el objeto que mandas como argumento es un `Model`:

```
<div id="saldos-section">
    @Html.Partial("ConsultaSaldo",
   /* Modelo -> */ new { SaldoRecargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas, SaldoServicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios })
</div>
```

Por lo tanto, intenta modificando tu vista parcial de la siguiente manera:

```
@model dynamic
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConsultaSaldo", "Recargas", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "formSaldos" }))
{
<div class="saldos">
    <div class="saldosservicios">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Servicios</h4>
        @if (Model.SaldoServicios != null)
        {
            <output class="totalsaldo" >@Model.SaldoServicios</output>                

        }
    </div>

    <div class="saldosrecargas">
        <h4 class="nombresaldo">Saldo Recargas</h4>
        @if (Model.SaldoRecargas != null)
        {
           <output class="totalsaldo">@Model.SaldoRecargas</output>
        }           
    </div>
  <div>
    <input class="btnConsultar" type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="Actualizar()"/>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

---

Lo mejor es que crees una clase modelo con las propiedades que estás pasando:

```
namespace TuSitio.Models
{
    public class ModeloDeVistaParcial
    {
        public decimal SaldoRecargas { get; set; }
        public decimal SaldoServicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lo pasas como el modelo a la vista parcial:

```
@Html.Partial("ConsultaSaldo",
              new TuSitio.Models.ModeloDeVistaParcial()
                  {
                      SaldoRecargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas,
                      SaldoServicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios
                  })
```

Y lo declaras como el modelo en esa vista:

```
@model TuSitio.Models.ModeloDeVistaParcial
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Probando! Saludos

Comment: Dejame comentarte que no me ha funcionado. Los valores de las propiedades del modelo llegan perfectamente a la vista, sin embargo siguen sin "imprimirse" en pantalla

Comment: ¿Realizaste el cambio de los `ViewBag` a `Model` en la vista parcial?

Comment: Así es, tal cual como esto "@model Consulta.UI.Web.Models.ValidarRecaudador" y para mostrar los valores algo como esto: "@Model.saldoServiciosField"

Answer (score 0):

`Html.Partial` y `Html.RenderPartial` no ejecuta los ciclos de un controlador como lo hace un request normal, lo que significa que los metodos del controlador no son ejecutados, sino que parsean el html de las vistas directamente y por lo tanto los valores del `ViewBag` nunca terminan siendo asignados.

Utiliza `Action.RenderAction(viewname, requestParameters)` que ejecuta los ciclos normales de un `Request` y se te mostraran los `ViewBag`s:

```
<div id="saldos-section">
@{  
   Html.RenderAction("ConsultaSaldo", new { SaldoRecargas = ViewBag.SaldoRecargas, SaldoServicios = ViewBag.SaldoServicios });
}
</div>
```